# SseEmitter handle client close on server - Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, server-sent-events

In my spring boot application i have SseController

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/sse")
public class SseController {

    @Autowired
    SseService sseService;
    
    @GetMapping("")
    public SseEmitter sse(@RequestParam String topic) {
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(-1L);
        sseService.addEmitter(topic, emitter);
        return emitter;
    }

}
```

and the service

```java
@Service
public class SseService implements NotificationService {

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper mapper;
    
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, CopyOnWriteArraySet<SseEmitter>> topicsEmitters = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    
    public void addEmitter(String topic, SseEmitter emitter) {
        if (this.topicsEmitters.containsKey(topic)) {
            this.topicsEmitters.get(topic).add(emitter);
        } else {
            CopyOnWriteArraySet<SseEmitter> emittersSet = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();
            emittersSet.add(emitter);
            this.topicsEmitters.put(topic, emittersSet);
        }
        emitter.onCompletion(() -> {
            this.removeEmitter(topic, emitter); 
        });
        emitter.onTimeout(() -> {
            this.removeEmitter(topic, emitter);
        });
    }
    
    public void removeEmitter(String topic, SseEmitter emitter) {
        if (this.topicsEmitters.get(topic).contains(emitter)) {
            this.topicsEmitters.get(topic).remove(emitter);
            emitter.complete();
        }
        if (this.topicsEmitters.get(topic).isEmpty()) {
            this.topicsEmitters.remove(topic);
        }
    }
    
    public void removeEmitters(String topic, Collection<SseEmitter> emitters) {
        if (emitters != null) {
            for (SseEmitter emitter: emitters) {
                this.removeEmitter(topic, emitter);
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void dispatch(String topic, NotificationEvent event, Class<?> serializationView) {
        if (this.topicsEmitters.containsKey(topic)) {
            Set<SseEmitter> disabledEmmitters = null;
            for (SseEmitter emitter: this.topicsEmitters.get(topic)) {
                try {
                    emitter.send(SseEmitter.event()
                            .name(event.getName())
                            .data(mapper.writerWithView(serializationView).writeValueAsString(event.getData()))
                    );
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    if (disabledEmmitters == null) {
                        disabledEmmitters = new HashSet<>();
                    }
                    disabledEmmitters.add(emitter);
                }
            }
            this.removeEmitters(topic, disabledEmmitters);
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that when i close the sse connection from the client, the server keeps the connections alive and continue to send events even if the client doesn't receive it.

Is there a way to handle connection close from the clients on the server ?

Comment: Have you tried with the `onError`? If would also suggest to use `computeIfAbsent` for your map instead of check if key exists, then add/create list etc. It will simplifly your code.

Comment: Yes i tried but it's not trigger when the connection is closed by the client